# What is the difference between referring to prototype of an object with explicitly specifying __proto__ and without?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand JavaScript internals. When it comes to JavaScript Prototypical inheritance with `__proto__`, I understand that each Object in JavaScript i.e Functions, Arrays, Object literals etc contains `__proto__` property which is used to refer **prototype**(Here prototype I mean a feature where other objects can get referenced to. Not the prototype property of a function Constructor) of those objects. For example, let's say I've an object called **myObject** with few properties and members

```
var myObject = {
   firstName:"Kishore",
   lastName:"Kumar",
   fullName: function() {
      console.log(this.firstName+" "+this.lastName);
   }
}
```

And I want **fullName** method to be inherited in following object i.e

```
var anotherObj = {
   firstName:"Anil"
}
```

So I did this

```
anotherObj.__proto__ = myObject;
```

So, What I understand from the above code snippet is, anotherObj's prototype is now referring to the same memory spot of myObject's fullName and have access to it. So I can invoke it with `anotherObj.__proto__.fullName()`. But some resources say, I can directly do this i.e `anotherObj.fullName()` and I can. And JavaScript engine internally takes care and makes fullName available by using prototype chain.

But now, here's what confuses me. When I was trying to change a property of an object that anotherObj's prototype referring to, i.e myObject's property, I came into this two weird problems.

1) When I do `anotherObj.lastName = "Korada";`, I expect the myObject that prototype of anotherObj pointed to, should change it's lastName. But it's not.

2) When I do `anotherObj.__proto__.lastName = "Korada";`, It changes.

So with the above two ways of pointing myObject through prototypical inheritance, I can see they are different. I want to know why? What is the difference between using explicitly with **`__proto__`** and without to access and modify the myObject's members in anotherObj?

Note: I understand using `__proto__` costs performance and we should never use it in the development. The question I asked is for understanding.

**Edited:** For better understanding my question, below I put two code snippets That I want to know difference for.

**Code1:**

```
var myObject = {
   firstName:"Kishore",
   lastName:"Kumar",
   fullName: function() {
      console.log(this.firstName+" "+this.lastName);
   }
}

var anotherObj = {
   firstName:"Anil"
}

anotherObj.__proto__ = myObject;
anotherObj.lastName = "Korada";
console.log(anotherObj.__proto__);
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Code2:**

```
var myObject = {
   firstName:"Kishore",
   lastName:"Kumar",
   fullName: function() {
      console.log(this.firstName+" "+this.lastName);
   }
}

var anotherObj = {
   firstName:"Anil"
}

anotherObj.__proto__ = myObject;
anotherObj.__proto__.lastName = "Korada";
console.log(anotherObj.__proto__);
```

**Output:**
[image]

You can see in the above two code snippets output, lastName effecting when I try to use **anotherObj.__proto__.lastName = "Korada";**

I just want to know why?

Comment: Only reading a property follows the prototype chain. Modifying a property affects the immediate object but nothing else.

Comment: When it comes to understanding prototype inheritance, **ignore the deprecated `__proto__`**! Use `Object.getPrototypeOf`/`Object.setPrototypeOf` instead.

Comment: "*So I did this `jane.__proto__ = anotherObj;`*" - are you sure? The rest of the text refers to them the other way round

Comment: @Bergi That's a naming conflict. The original example was jane actually. But I used here as anotherObj

Comment: @Bergi I understand that it's deprecated and I should never use. But conceptually I want to understand, what's the difference with or without using __proto__ when referring prototype that refers to other objects

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada It still looks like you meant `anotherObj.__proto__ = myObject` (or rather, `Object.setPrototypeOf(anotherObj, myObject)`) - what you currently have throws an exception.

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada Given that `Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherObj)` is `myObject`, as you seem to have understood, the difference between `anotherObj.lastName = "Korada"` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherObj).lastName = "Korada"` is **exactly** the difference between `anotherObj.lastName = "Korada"` and `myObject.lastName = "Korada"`.

Comment: @Bergi edited. Generally, I want to inherit from myObject to anotherObj. But here I can invoke myObject's properties and methods from anotherObj just with anotherObj.lastName. Also with anotherObj.__proto__.lastName. So want to understand what's the difference?

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada What is the difference between `anotherObj.lastName = "Korada"` and `myObject.lastName = "Korada"`? Try to tell me.

Comment: Also, if you compare `myObject.fullName()` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherObj).fullName()` with `anotherObj.fullName()`, it should be obvious what the difference for method calls is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149273/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-korada-and-bergi).

Comment: is your output for code snippet 1 the right screen capture?

Comment: Well `anotherObj.lastName = "Korada";` created the property on `anotherObj` whereas `anotherObj.__proto__.lastName = "Korada";` created the property on `myObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to JavaScript's prototypal model, and the concept of prototype chaining.

In short, the concept can be summarised by:

> Each object has a private property (referred to as [[Prototype]] ) which holds a link to another object called its prototype. That prototype object has a prototype of its own, and so on until an object is reached with null as its prototype. By definition, null has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain.

So you can see things as a chain. In your case, for both code 1 and code 2, what you have set up is a chain like this:

```
anotherObj --> myObject --> null
```

Which can also be seen as:

```
{firstName: "Anil"} --> {firstName: "Kishore", lastName: "Kumar", fullName: function} --> null
```

So, when you try to access a property, it will move along the prototype chain, beginning from the point where you access it. In code 1, you accessed the `lastName` property from `anotherObj`, making that the 'entry point'. Since `anotherObj` has the `lastName` property, the property has been found, and will be modified directly when you did `anotherObj.lastName = "Korada";`. As the property has been found and modified, the search stops there.

Meanwhile, for code 2, you accessed the `lastName` property from the prototype object when you did `anotherObj.__proto__.lastName`, which is `myObject`. This means that the search begins from there, and as the property `lastName` is first found in `myObject`, the `lastName` property in `myObject` will be modified to the new value.

The reason why you can refer directly to the `fullName()` function in `myObject` when you 'enter' the chain from `anotherObj` is because `anotherObj` does not have this function, so the search continues up the chain, and is found in `myObject`.

I hope my explanation is right (do point out if there's something wrong!). Also, feel free to refer to a helpful link like this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain